# "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" with GreaseMonkey script

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have the following GreaseMonkey script. It basically adds a button to a page that already has a lot of buttons. Clicking that added button should trigger w/e function is associated with clicking all the other buttons. However, when I click the triggerAllButton, I get an error `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object` in the console. Any ideas what's wrong with this code? I replaced the links in `@include` and `@exclude` with `...` as I don't want them public.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Test Stuff
// @description Test
// @include ...
// @require .../static/jquery.min.js
// @require .../static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
// @require .../static/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js
// @require .../static/datatables/js/DT_bootstrap.js
// @require .../static/toastr/toastr.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-text.pull-right')
        .append('<input type="button" id="triggerAllButton" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="Trigger All">');
});

$(function(){
    $('#triggerAllButton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".btn.trigger").each(function() {
            $(this).trigger();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `.trigger()` incorrectly, you need to pass at least the event type argument.

```
$('#triggerAllButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".btn.trigger").trigger("click"); //.each is implicit on all jQuery methods
});
```

Comment: Ah, right you are! Silly mistake. Though, even when I specify the event to trigger, nothing happens. I tried colorizing the buttons with CSS and that works, but emulating a click just does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: @mart1n You need to debug it with alerts or console and see where the trail stops